# Start onActivityResult not being called from menu option

Tags: android, menu, onactivityresult

I have an **Activity A** and **Activity B** and the problem is I'm unable to call the `onActivityResult` in Activity A from B using menu option.

Now this is how I go to Activity A from B

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        return true;
    case R.id.category_add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Now in Activity B I perform some operations and get back to Activity A as shown

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        return true;
    case R.id.task_add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        startActivity(intent );
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now in Activity A onActivityResult which is not calling:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
        if (data != null) {
            sampledata= data.getStringExtra("sampletext");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.sample.example.ActivityA"
    android:label="@string/title_sample_app"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Default" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityB"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Default" >
</activity>
```

Comment: @downvoter- Can you please let me know why did you downvote? Just simply don't downvote.. For future readers it will be helpful with your comment. Or is that something wrong with my question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're starting an Activity again from Activity B.

The correct way (if you started an Activity for result) is to finish it like this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Some more Information:

- To learn more about starting Activities (for result), read: [Starting Activities and Getting Results](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)
- To learn more about getting results from other apps (could be interesting, too), read: [Interacting with Other Apps - Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: @theMfromA- Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 2):

To return back to `ActivityA`, you don't want to start it again but to finish `ActivityB`

```
case R.id.task_add:
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras( whatever you need to pass back to A);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
    break
```

check for typo